# Eliminate $z$ from these two hyperbolic functions.

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

I was going through my textbook and was stuck at this one, i tried to do substitution but in vain, can you help me or give me a hint as to how to approach this problem?
**Eliminate $z$ from these equations:
$$ p\cdot \text{cosech} (z) + q\cdot \text{sech} (z) +r=0  $$
$$p'\cdot \text{cosech}(z) + q'\cdot \text{sech} (z) +r'=0 $$**

Comment: You could possibly write them out in terms of $e^z$, $e^{-z}$ and solve this for $z$

Comment: @JohnDoe aH! im feeling dumb to not spotting that earlier.

Comment: Anyway thanks bro.

Comment: No problem! ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get by definitions
$$\frac{2p}{e^z-e^{-z}}+\frac{2q}{e^z+e^{-z}}+r=0$$
Substituting $$e^z=t$$ we get
$$\frac{2pt}{t^2-1}+\frac{2qt}{t^2+1}+r=0$$
and you have to solve
$$rt^4+t^3(2p-2q)+t(2p-2q)-r=0$$

Comment: Alright , thanks

Comment: i will work the solution .

Comment: Have a nice evening or whatever is there in your country. :-)

Comment: Thank you , i will working further to solve problems